# Matching rasters do not work in foreach loop

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, raster, unmarked-package

I'm working on a habitat occupancy prediction encompassing the entire state of Wyoming.  Certain site covariate rasters work in the prediction while others with matched resolution, extent, etc. do not.

A short reproduceable example of my code is below.  After extensive troubleshooting I've found I have 3 rasters of the 5 I need to use that cause this script to fail, all with the same error.
I'm assuming my rasters have somehow become corrupted(?) but wanted to see if anyone has another idea on what could be happening.

Data is at [this link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjAEIqbr5WDtgRfLayHZd_ADjkBB?e=7z1Yvm).  The data is the unmarked object (saved as .rds) and 2 very small clips off of: 1. the raster that works, and 2. one of the rasters that does not work

#### Steps I took to originally align the rasters for stacking - for information purposes

```r
#ndvi <- raster(paste(getwd(), "./Original_rasters/ndvi_summer.TIF", sep = ""))

#precip <- raster(paste(getwd(), "./Original_rasters/bioclim15.TIF", sep = ""))

#temp <- projectExtent(original, original)
#res(temp) <- 220

#sNoJoy <- resample(ndvi, temp)
#sampleJoy <- resample(precip, temp)
```

#### Start here for reproducing error

```r
library(raster)
library(unmarked)
sampleData <- readRDS("./sampleData.RDS")

# Formula referencing raster that does not work
fmTest <- occu(~ Day + Min_TempC + AvailTN_prop ~ ndvi.summer, 
               sampleData)
fmTest

# Formula referencing raster that DOES work
#fmTest <- occu(~ Day + Min_TempC + AvailTN_prop ~ bc15_220, 
#               sampleData)

# Formula for both variables that fails also
#fmTest <- occu(~ Day + Min_TempC + AvailTN_prop ~ ndvi.summer + bc15_220,
#               sampleData)

# Load and name rasters so formulas can find them
sampleJoy <- raster(paste(getwd(), "./sampleGoodRas.TIF", sep = ""))
names(sampleJoy) <- "bc15_220"
sNoJoy <- raster(paste(getwd(), "./sampleBadRas.TIF", sep = ""))
names(sNoJoy) <- "ndvi.summer"

compareRaster(sampleJoy, sNoJoy) # Returns "[1] TRUE"
 
# pm <- stack(sampleJoy)
pm <- stack(sNoJoy)
# pm <- stack(sNoJoy, sampleJoy)

###########################Combine Function#####################################

comb <- function(x, ...) {
  mapply("rbind", x, ..., SIMPLIFY = F)
}

# This combine function allows foreach to return a list containing multiple 
# matrices making it easy to insert results into raster templates

############################ Foreach Code #####################################
#Assemble cluster for parallel processing.  Code works in Windows or other O/S#

ifelse(Sys.info()["sysname"] != "Windows", 
       c(require(doMC), nc <- detectCores()-1, registerDoMC(nc)),
       c(require(doParallel), nc <- detectCores()-1, cl <- makeCluster(nc), 
         registerDoParallel(cl)))

# Foreach loop returning predicted values, SE, LCI, and UCI
pred <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(pm), .combine = comb, .multicombine = T,
                .maxcombine = 90,
                .packages = c("unmarked", "raster")) %dopar% {
  
  # make raster into a data.frame row by row for prediction
  tmp <- as.data.frame(pm[i,], xy = T)
  
  # Predict the new data
  pred <- predict(fmTest, "state", tmp)
  
  # Make a list of 4 matrices to retrieve them from the loop      
  list(Predicted = pred$Predicted,
       SE = pred$SE,
       lower = pred$lower,
       upper = pred$upper)
}

# Close the cluster
stopCluster(cl)

## Using sampleJoy produces a list of 4 matrices which are easily coerced into
## raster format: Prediction, SE, lower, and upper, as it should.

## Using sNoJoy produces:  
# Error in { : 
# task 1 failed - "Matrices must have same number of rows in 
# cbind2(.Call(dense_to_Csparse, x), y)" 

## Rasters are the same extent, same origin, same resolution, etc.
# 

### Not Working
# > pm
# class      : RasterStack 
# dimensions : 15, 2675, 40125, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
# resolution : 220, 220  (x, y)
# extent     : 201539.7, 790039.7, 647050.2, 650350.2  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=lcc +lat_0=41 +lon_0=-107.5 +lat_1=41 +lat_2=45 +x_0=500000 +y_0=200000 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs 
# names      : ndvi.summer 
# min values :  0.09507491 
# max values :   0.8002191 
# 

### Working Raster
# > pm
# class      : RasterStack 
# dimensions : 15, 2675, 40125, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
# resolution : 220, 220  (x, y)
# extent     : 201539.7, 790039.7, 647050.2, 650350.2  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=lcc +lat_0=41 +lon_0=-107.5 +lat_1=41 +lat_2=45 +x_0=500000 +y_0=200000 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs 
# names      : bc15_220 
# min values :       14 
# max values :       66
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

The error arises because you have missings in `sNoJoy`. Had those not been missing, it would have worked just fine.

**Question rewritten**

Your problem has nothing to do with your parallel code. It boils down to this:

```r
fmTest <- occu(~ Day + Min_TempC + AvailTN_prop ~ ndvi.summer, sampleData)
fmTest2 <- occu(~ Day + Min_TempC + AvailTN_prop ~ bc15_220, sampleData)

pm <- stack(sNoJoy)
pm2 <- stack(sampleJoy)

tmp <- as.data.frame(pm[1,], xy = T)
tmp2 <- as.data.frame(pm2[1,], xy = T)

pred <- predict(fmTest, "state", tmp) # fails
pred2 <- predict(fmTest2, "state", tmp2) # works
```

**Rationale**

As it turns out, your bad raster has missing values:

```r
table(is.na(sNoJoy[]))
#FALSE  TRUE 
#35998  4127
```

If we artificially remove the `NA`s in `sNoJoy` and randomly write 1 `NA` in `sampleJoy`, then the states flip:

```r
sNoJoy[is.na(sNoJoy[])] <- 1
sampleJoy[10] <- NA

### run same code as above

pred <- predict(fmTest, "state", tmp) # now works
pred2 <- predict(fmTest2, "state", tmp2) # now fails
```

Thus, I would try to figure out why you have `NA`s to begin with.

Comment: Interesting.  I don't recall having this issue with NA values in rasters previously, but I believe you're right.  There are a ton of NA values in my rasters.  I wonder if that's from the manipulation to match them up/stack them